# Check if a value exits in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Customer's Node

```
customers
 {
 "-KXKCee0yVJE1z1gCQcV" : {
"cust_id" : "-KXKCee0yVJE1z1gCQcV",
"email" : “xxx@xxx.com",
"food_pref" : "nonveg",
"name" : “Jind",
"notes" : "",
"phone" : “123"
 },
 "-KXMVChcSwfUif-xVbRa" : {
"cust_id" : "-KXMVChcSwfUif-xVbRa",
"email" : “ggg@ggg.com",
"food_pref" : "nonveg",
"name" : “Mani",
"notes" : "Butter Chicken!!!",
"phone" : “456"
  },
  "-KXV4eYM6bKNniE_oLEf" : {
"cust_id" : "-KXV4eYM6bKNniE_oLEf",
"email" : “vvv@vvv.com",
"food_pref" : "veg",
"name" : "Jay",
"notes" : "",
"phone" : “789"
 }
}
```

I'm using the following query to check Phone Number

```
Query query = reference.child("customers").orderByChild("phone").equalTo("789");
```

How do I check if the value "789" exists?

Tried doing

```
 query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey());
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Not Found");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
```

This does not work.Any alternate for checking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)).

The `ChildEventListener` will be invoked only if the child exists. If it doesn't, nothing will happen.

The `ValueEventListener` will always be invoked and you can call the snapshot's [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()) method to check for existence.