# Show the Message "No More" At last element of for Add Child Event Listener In Android java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

**I am facing problem to check whether child exists or not inside database add listenter !**

I have tried the below code:

```
  Shorted.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No more  Users", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
});
```

> No toast message appears.

Comment: Are you doing it in a frag I think , And u doing it in a loaddata?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect whether a child exists with a `ChildEventListener`. The reason is that `onChildAdded` is only called for existing child nodes. If there are no child nodes, it isn't called.

So you'll need a `ValueEventListener` to detect the case where there are no child nodes. Something like:

```
Shorted.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No users", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
});
```

Also see:

- [how to know if firebase ChildEventListener found child ? [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521884/how-to-know-if-firebase-childeventlistener-found-child-android)
- [Check if a value exits in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648599/check-if-a-value-exits-in-firebase)
- [Start next activity if firebase database has no child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165807/start-next-activity-if-firebase-database-has-no-child-value)
- [Why this ChildEventListener is not reading data from firebase node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447911/why-this-childeventlistener-is-not-reading-data-from-firebase-node)

Comment: Hey, I need that for add child listener, not for value event listener. I also know that answer but it is not required!

Comment: provide correct answer!

Comment: You cannot detect whether a child exists with a `ChildEventListener`.

Comment: We can detect the last element of that!

Comment: show message at last element

Comment: There is no way to know what is the last time `onChildAdded` gets called, as the concept of 'last' is not hard to define when it comes to data that can be updated at any time. That's also why I switched to using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in my answer, as that ensures we're just talking about "right now there are no child nodes".

Comment: Some problems, Can't be solved by a genius progammer!